# Deleting directory in finally block?

Tags: java, file

I'm creating a temporary directory to do some housekeeping tasks and want to delete it as soon as all these tasks done. The thing is these jobs can throw exceptions, but I still don't want to delete all these tons of temporary files manually. Here is how it looks like:

```
try{
   Path p = //tmp dir
   doJob1(p);
   doJob2(p);
} finally{
   p.toFile().delete();
}
```

The thing is I have never seen something like that. Releasing locks in `finally` block -- is common. But what about deleting files? Are there some drawbacks?

Comment: Consider using https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit--  - that may do the job for you.

Comment: @davida 'delete on exit' creates a list of files to be deleted, which on a longer running process (e.g. a webserver) will be a memory hog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One drawback with your current implementation is that there is no Exception handling in the finally block. The delete method on File can throw a SecurityException (i.e. you can't access the resource for whatever reason).
Another drawback could be that this is problematic if you decide to run your jobs asynchronously using Callables / Runnables. In that case the finally block might try to execute before your jobs are done and will probably fail.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `p` is a file, and not a directory you might replace `p.toFile().delete()` with

```
Files.delete(p);
```

or

```
Files.deleteIfExists(p);
```

If it is a directory you will need to (recursively) delete the files and folders in it.

Answer (score 1):

> But what about deleting files? Are there some drawbacks?

There are some concerns:

1. You cannot delete a directory that contains any files.  The files (or directories) in the directory must be deleted first.
2. On some platforms (e.g. Windows) you cannot delete a file that is currently open.

Comment: I knew that something was wrong with that. Thank you.